# JQuery extend custom object with parameters

Tags: jquery, object, parameters, extend

there might be an easier way to achieve what i'm trying to do and i don't think i completely understand `$.extend()` function, but here i am seeking for an advise:

i have this custom grid object defined on my index:

```
var grid = $('.grid').loadGrid({
            inlineEditing:<?php echo $edit ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>,
            adding:<?php echo $edit ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>,
            deleting:<?php echo $edit ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>,
            pagerLocation:"top",
            width:1320,
            loadComplete: function() {
                exp_sql = $(this).data().exp_sql;
            }
        });
```

as you can see some of the parameters are worked out while PHP processing the page.

i have then below on the page several grids defined with some var check beforehand:

```
<?
$tab = '1';
if(!@in_array($tab,$SECTIONS,true) AND $LEVEL != 1){ $edit = 0;}
?>

<table class="grid cat" action="div-m.php" title="Master catalogue info">
   <th col="Catalogue"  editable="<?php echo $edit ? 'select' : ''; ?>">Catalogue No</th>
   <th col="ISRC" editable="<?php echo $edit ? 'text' : ''; ?>">ISRC</th>
   ...
</table>
```

then:

```
...
<table class="grid isrc" action="div-d.php" title="Digital / detailed info">
...
</table>
```

each of the separate tables have their unique `date_ranges` (from mysql table)
which should be defined in main grid for each table.. but because i have several grids on the same page i cannot do it with PHP.

so the question is - can i extend the firstly defined object `grid` with more options straight before the table, i.e.:

```
<?php
    $tab = '1';
    $grid = 'cat';
    if(!@in_array($tab,$SECTIONS,true) AND $LEVEL != 1){ $edit = 0;}
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var date = {dateRange:"street_date"};
        $.extend.apply(grid, date);
    //  $.extend(grid, dateRange:"street_date");
    </script>
    <table class="grid cat" action="div-m.php" title="Master catalogue info">
```

the above obviously doesn't work... because i think `loadGrid()` method should be called again...